# SMTP Server for MAC - Any suggestions?

Tags: php, email, smtp

I'm doing PHP development on my MacBook and have reached the email functionality of the book I'm using.

Are there any good SMTP servers for Mac?

Cheers,

Billy

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Postfix is usually built in: http://www.david-reitter.com/software/osxpostfix.html

Answer (score 4):

CommandLineFu had [this one liner](http://www.commandlinefu.com/commands/view/134/python-smtp-server) to run an SMTP server on port 25:

```
sudo python -m smtpd -n -c DebuggingServer localhost:25
```

This will run a fake smtp server on your local machine. It won't send anything, but will dump it to the console.

Comment: Cool. I needed a to verify an email notification service locally on my mac and this worked like a charm!

Answer (score 2):

http://www.phase2technology.com/node/667/

But do you really need a SMTP-Server of your own?

Comment: Just so I can make sure my code is correct. I could upload it to my hosting site but I'd rather do it straight from me mac

Comment: Then I would suggest to add a complete SMTP protocol[1], since the php_mail() function is very buggy[2] and makes problems very often, especially with RFC-conform MTAs (like qmail). [1] http://drupal.org/node/29888 [2] http://bugs.php.net/bug.php?id=15841

Comment: This is the better answer now. The chosen answer's link is broken.

Comment: I needed a simple way to send mails from my build server on OSX Snow Leopard and this worked like a charm within 5 minutes. Thanks!

Comment: The link given above is now also broken

Answer (score 1):

Old thread, but for anyone else landing here.  I just found this app:

http://mocksmtpapp.com/

It's a super simple SMTP test server for mac osx.  It comes with a very simply gui that allows you to see the messages you have sent.  Obviously it's not a "real" server (i.e. it doesn't relay) but for simply testing sending emails it works perfectly.

Comment: For anyone landing here: This domain no longer works